# Double Looping in SAS

Tags: sas

This problem might be trivial but I got stuck.

My problem is I've to go to each folder for a dataset and transpose the data.

I wrote the following code and it works fine.

```
OPTIONS MPRINT MLOGIC SYMBOLGEN;

%LET LOC=E:\folder;

%macro test1(k,l);

libname libary "&loc.\&k\&l.";

data dataset_&l.;
set libary.dataset_original;
run;


proc transpose data=dataset_&l. out=dataset_&l._T;
run;

%mend;

%test1(var_1,var'_1);
%test1(var_2,var'_2);
%test1(var_3,var'_3);
```

The issue with this code is it's not dynamic in terms of folder structure. E.g. if there's another 4 extra folders, I've to write `"%test1(var_3,var'_3);"`4 times.

So I tried writing the following code to make it more dynamic. But unfortunately it's not working. Can anybody please tell me where I'm making the mistake.

```
OPTIONS MPRINT MLOGIC SYMBOLGEN;

%LET LOC=E:\folder;

%let k=var_1 var_2 var_3;

%let l=var'_1 var'_2 var'_3;

%macro words(string);
  %local count word;
  %let count=1;
  /* The third argument of the %QSCAN function specifies the delimiter */
  %let word=%qscan(&string,&count,%str( ));
  %do %while(&word ne);
    %let count=%eval(&count+1);
    %let word=%qscan(&string,&count,%str( ));
  %end;
  %eval(&count-1)
%mend words;

%macro test1(k,l);

libname libary "&loc.\&k\&l.";

data dataset_&l.;
set libary.dataset_original;
run;


proc transpose data=dataset_&l. out=dataset_&l._T;
run;

%mend;


%macro test();

%do i=1 %to %words(&k.);
%do j=1 %to %words(&l.);
%let var=%scan(&k.,&i.,str());
%let var1=%scan(&l.,&j.,str());
%test1(&var.,&var1.);

%end;
%end;

%mend;

%test();
```

Thanks!

Comment: So you're looping through _directories_ and subdirectories and transposing any SAS datasets in them? Or am I not understanding?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Alex!. Yes, I'm trying to loop directories and sub-directories. Now both directories and sub-directories are changing simultaneously. So, for folder var_1, sub-folder will be var'_1. It will never be the case the folder will remain constant but sub-folder changes.

Comment: What operating system are you on? You could get a list of files by piping `dir` with a `*.sas7bdat` filter and the recursive option on Windows, and reading that into a dataset and doing `call execute()`.

Comment: @AlexA.: I'm using windows. Can you please give me some example for the suggestions that you provided. I'm not much aware of it. There 1 more thing. In the folder there are multiple subfolders. And I'm selecting a single subfolder out of multiple subfolder. So if I create a list of subfolders and then pass it into my program, that does not work much as there also I've to manually select a folder. Thanks!

Comment: What's with the `'` character?  You can't have that in a dataset name or anything like that.

Comment: Look into data-driven programming as a keyword for this.  You shouldn't be looping in the macro over the folder or anything like that - you should be generating a dataset with the parameters to the macro calls and then using that to generate the macro calls.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks Joe for you comment.I used ' just to differentiate 2 folder names (folder and subfolder.) E.g var_1 is the folder and var'_1 is the subfolder within var_1. The actual folder name are different and follows SAS programming naming guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```c
/* Set your base directory */
%let base = E:\Folder;

/* Pipe output from dir */
filename flist pipe "dir /s /b /a:-h &base";

/* Read files from pipe */
data files;
    length file dir $ 200 name $ 50 ext $ 10;

    infile flist;
    input @1 file $ &;

    /* File extension */
    ext = scan(file, -1, ".");

    /* File name */
    name = scan(scan(file, -1, "\"), 1, ".");

    /* Directory */
    rfile = reverse(file);
    dir = reverse(substr(rfile, index(rfile, "\") + 1));

    /* Select only SAS datasets */
    if upcase(ext) = "SAS7BDAT" then output;

    drop rfile;
run;


/* Define a macro to process each file */
%macro trans_file(dir, name);

    libname d "&dir";

    proc transpose data = d.&name out = d.&name._t;
    run;

    libname d clear;

%mend trans_file;


/* Run on all files */
data _null_;
    set files;
    call execute(cats('%trans_file(', dir, ",", name, ");"));
run;
```

This gets the file list by submitting the [Windows command `dir`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html). It gets all files in the specified directory and its subdirectories.

This approach then uses a simple macro that defines a data library, reads a dataset from the library, writes a transposed dataset to it, then clears it. The macro is called for each file in the list using [`call execute`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67398/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1blnvlvciwgs9n0zcilud6d6ei9.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex for your help. I'll try this and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer. There's one issue with your code, but I modified your code for my problem. My setup was, there's number of folders, and each folder there are number of subfolders, and within them there are number of sas dataset. And I've to pick 1 specific folder, subfolder and sas dataset to transform. But your code was transforming all sas datasets for all folder and subfolders. So I edited your code and it's working fine.